# Create a student account in Azure

Tags: azure, azure-machine-learning-service

I would like to start with Azure Machine Learning and I have seen that if you have a student account, you can get a 100$ and access to Azure Machine Learning for free ... But when I try to register, Azure ask me a Windows Account (hotmail, outlook...) and my student account is gmail. So what Can I do?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to SO; please do take some time to read [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and notice that questions asking for *support for offsite resources* such as App Stores are off-topic for Stack Overflow. Direct your questions to the relevant organisation instead (of course you could just open a hotmail/outlook account...). Plus, question has nothing to do with `machine-learning` - kindly do not spam irrelevant tags (removed).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about support for offsite resources.

Answer (score 1):

Please just follow the process. To use Azure, you need to have a Microsoft account. The process will ask you to verify your Student status and school email address, then you are good to go and get the credit. Please let me know if you have other questions. Hope you enjoy using Azure Machine Learning Service.

Regards,
Yutong